# Opening browser's home page in other than IIE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, html

I'm writing a bit of code to display an EU Cookie notification.

If the visitor does not accept the use of cookies, I want to take them somewhere else. My first thought was to take them to the browser's home page.

[I found a way to do it in IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531398(VS.85).aspx) - I have been told that the method on that page is for IE 10 or less.

I have not found a way to do so in other browsers.

If this turns out to be more trouble than it is worth, I'll take them somewhere via a specific URL, such as www.google.com

Does anyone know of the method to accomplish the same thing in browsers such as Firefox, Safari, Chrome, etc?

Comment: Just so you know, question marks go at the _end_ of a question, not the start.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers implement an address that will point to the home page. You should be able to redirect the user to the proper location after you figure out their browser.

For Chrome you can link them to `about:newtab`, which may be different from the home page, but it is probably the closest you will find. The actual homepage button is not implemented in Javascript and does not use a URL.

For Firefox you can link to `about:home`.

For Opera you can link to `opera:speeddial`. (I did not test this one, if someone wants to I'll update)

The documentation you linked to claims to be obsolete after IE10. I think you can link to `about:home` on IE same as Firefox if your solution isn't working afer IE10. (I did not test this one, if someone wants to I'll update).

Comment: Testing: <a href="about:home">test</a>

Seems to only work properly with IE (I've got IE 10 installed) but n ot with Firefox or Chrome.

Firefox - goes to what looks like Firefox's default home page, not what I set as the home page.

IChrome - takes me to about:blank

Clicking the Home button in the toolbar of Firefox and Chrome takes me to the Home page that I set in the browser settings.

Any ideas as how to make this work properly for FF and Chrome?

Comment: Is there a way to enter a blank line while typing a comment so that it is easier to read the comment?

Comment: A bit more about Chrome - href="about:newtab" also takes me to about:blank --- remember the Home button will take me to the Home page. Opening a new tab takes me to a Google search page.

Comment: This is just another in "we'll do it the way we want to" for browsers, rather than true compatibility! I think I'll just take them to the "Cause du jour" like http://fortune.com/2017/04/25/trump-fcc-net-neutrality/

Comment: @SimonT Sorry, a little late, but `shift + enter` will let you do blank lines